# Unable to establish ssh connection : No authentication methods available

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run nodes on two different machines within the same launch file, so I am using the `<machine>` tag to do so.

`<machine name="roboRIO" address=10.9.0.29" env-loader="path/to/script" user="admin" />`

The user doesn't require a password. I can definitely ssh onto the remote host with that same IP. I'm not sure what the problem could be. Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283801/unable-to-establish-ssh-connection-:-no-authentication-methods-available/) by [amstrudy](https://answers.ros.org/users/31757/amstrudy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-02-28**:
Try specifying the environment loader script on your second machine. Have a look [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/machine) on how to do so.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-02-28**:
Also ROS uses different SSH key algorithm than the one used with default SSH client. Have a look [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/244060/roslaunch-ssh-known_host-errors-cannot-launch-remote-nodes/) on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The key to answering this was actually adding a password. There was some weirdness while trying to log into the second device via ssh with a blank password.

---

Originally posted by [amstrudy](https://answers.ros.org/users/31757/amstrudy/) with karma: 43 on 2018-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0